# Getting SQLite3::SQLException: no such table error for Rails Tutorial's sample app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, railstutorial.org

I am trying to build the sample app in Rails Tutorial 3rd edition. On Chapter 11, it starts with adding a new model for microposts. However, When run the migrate, it throws below error

== 20141212145132 CreateEntries: migrating ====================================
-- create_table(:microposts)
-- add_index(:microposts, [:user_id, :created_at])
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: main.microposts: CREATE  INDEX "index_entries_on_user_id_and_created_at" ON "microposts" ("user_id", "created_at")/

Comment: Can you post the migration file code?

Comment: class CreateEntries < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :microposts do |t|
      t.text :content
      t.references :user, index: true

      t.timestamps
      add_index :microposts, [:user_id, :created_at]
    end
  end
end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing these lines

```
class CreateMicroposts < ActiveRecord::Migration  # <==== convention 
  def change 
    create_table :microposts do |t| 
      t.text :content 
      t.references :user, index: true 
      t.timestamps 
      t.index [:user_id, :created_at]  # <=== 
    end 
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got it now what I was doing wrong.

I had added the "add index" at the end of the of "def change" instead of after it. This is the code which is working now...

```
class CreateEntries < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :entries do |t|
      t.text :content
      t.references :user, index: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  add_index :entries, [:user_id, :created_at]
  end
end
```